# Mac: Associate two files

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a way (hopefully built into OSX) to make two files always stay together.

The purpose: give every file used in my classes (mostly PDFs and PPTs) a "summary file" -- which could just be an RTF I edit in TextEdit.

The point is for the two files (a text and my summary of it) to always be linked together.

Comment: Put them both in a folder?

Comment: Linked together like how? So that when you move or delete one file, all get moved or deleted?